# How can you filter a Deeply Nested XML using LINQ (streaming only), while maintaining the Tree Structure?

Tags: xml, linq, streaming

I would like to know how to stream over a very large, deeply nested, XML Document using LINQ, while streaming it, filter nodes based on some criteria and then write the streamed output to a file, while maintaining the same original structure of the XML.

This should happen without loading the entire document into memory.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This paper contains the answer to my question:

http://homepages.cwi.nl/~ralf/api-streaming-xml/

Specifically it shows how to maintain tree structure of an original XML when filtering the results while streaming.

Answer (score 1):

LINQ to XML doesn't support reading in a streaming fashion directly, but I've had success in using an `XmlReader`, filtering based on *that*, and then passing it to [`XElement.Load`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb355742.aspx) when I've discovered the subtree I'm interested in. It assumes that the subtree is small enough to fit into memory. When `Load` returns, the reader will have been moved beyond that subtree, and you can keep going until you find the next relevant subtree, etc.

See [this MSDN blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/xmlteam/archive/2007/03/24/streaming-with-linq-to-xml-part-2.aspx) for more information and sample code.

(This is what I did with the Stack Overflow data dump, btw :)

Comment: Hi Jon

Funny, I was just watching this video of you while this answer was posted:
http://skillsmatter.com/podcast/open-source-dot-net/jon-skeet-talks-on-c-sharp-3-0

With regards to the answer, wouldnt that result in an flat output?  I know how to stream in the XML using XMLReader and feeding it to LINQ one by one, my problem is upon filtering I loose the XML structure on the output.

Answer (score 0):

For XML streaming options, check out the XML Team's discussion of streaming with LINQ to XML starting with http://blogs.msdn.com/xmlteam/archive/2007/03/05/streaming-with-linq-to-xml-part-1.aspx. Realize that it is an early blog series and there were some implementation detail changes made in the final release.

Comment: Hi, I read that , the problem is that they do not go into depth about dealing with deeply nested structures.
They do refer to this on a future PART 3 on the series, put I couldnt never find it, I can only find part 1 and 2.